# Group by an array's element in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by

In Postgres 8.3, I need to group by certain elements within an array field. When I group by the array itself, all possible combinations are shown. I only want to group by the element.

something like this works for finding the count of a single element:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table
WHERE foo=any(bar)
```

this will return the correct count for a single element in an array. How do I return multiple counts for all elements in an array? If I group by the array, it will use all array elements in the identical order they are stored (not what I need).

edit for clarity:
bar is an array with values like {foo, some, thing} or {foo, thing} or {some, thing, else}

I want to know how many records have an element value of foo, some, thing, and else in the array "bar".

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
GROUP BY bar[4]
```

Comment: is this the actual syntax? I am running 8.3, and not getting it to work with your syntax. I will update my question with a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. you can't group by a value.. but of course the value is the column that contains it...
So.. you might want this:

```
SELECT AVG(blah), foo
FROM whatever
WHERE foo=any(bar)
GROUP BY foo
```

should work..

Comment: that doesn't work for me. if bar = {f,o,o} your example is: SELECT AVG(), f FROM whatever WHERE f=any(bar) group by f